# Itertools permutation and combination with fixed placement

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I want to permute an array where r=3. All three positions have some fixed positions. Position rule goes:

```
(arr[:3], arr[:3], arr[:7])
```

another rule: One element occurs only once. (1,2,2) is not acceptable. The resulted three elements should be unique.

the current pseudo is something like:

```
result = []
for h1 in arr[:3]:
    for h2 in arr[:3]:
        if h1 == h2:
            continue
        for h3 in arr[:7]:
            if h1 == h3 or h2 == h3:
                continue
            result.append([h1,h2,h3])
```

This means in the first place there can be only the elements ranging from index 0 to 2. The second position also has the same and the third position will have the elements ranging from 0-6.

I want to do the combinations also with the same rule.

I wrote a custom function that generates it perfectly. I was just wondering if there is any handy itertools function that does the job. Is there any?

Comment: That sounds like you're looking for a cartesian product.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.product`

```
import itertools 
for ele in itertools.product(arr[:3], arr[:3], arr[:7]):
    print(ele)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I'm sorry that some information was missing. I'm sorry about that. I have updated the question. Please take a look.